# Searching for block of characters (word) in a text

Tags: c, string, algorithm, search

I want to search for a block of characters (word) in a text.
For example, I have the next text "Hello xyz world", and I want to search for "xyz ", note the space after the word.

```
// The Text
const char * text = "Hello xyz world";
// The target word
const char * patt = "xyz ";
size_t textLen = strlen(text),
  pattLen = strlen(patt), i, j;

for (i = 0; i < textLen; i++) {
  printf("%c", text[i]);
  for (j = 0; j < pattLen; j++) {
    if (text[i] == patt[j]) {
      printf(" <--");
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

The result must be like following:

[image]

But unfortunately, the result as the following:

[image]

It collects all the similar characters in the whole text, not just the target characters (the word).

How to fix that problem?

Comment: Just not to overlook the obvious: string.h has function strstr that does the job.

Comment: @ZenJ: Yes, I know but it doesn't give me the ability to manipulate the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that there is a full match before starting to print any `<--`. And to avoid to do  accesses passed end of array on `patt`, you will have to stop searching when less than `pattLen` characters remain in array.

Then when you have found a full match, you can print the content of `patt` followed with `<--` and increment position of pointer of `pattLen-1`. And at the end you will have to copy remaining characters from text.

Code could become:

```
// The Text
const char * text = "Hello xyz world";
// The target word
const char * patt = "xyz ";
size_t textLen = strlen(text),
    pattLen = strlen(patt), i, j;

for (i = 0; i <= textLen - pattLen; i++) {  // don't search if less that pattLen remains
    printf("%c", text[i]);
    if (text[i] == patt[0]) {               // first char matches
        int found = 1;                      // be optimistic...
        for (j = 1; j < pattLen; j++) {
            if (patt[j] != text[i + j]) {
                found = 0;
                break;                      // does not fully match, go on
            }
        }
        if (found) {                        // yeah, a full match!
            printf(" <--");                 // already printed first char
            for (j = 1; j < pattLen; j++) {
                printf("\n%c <--", patt[j]);// print all others chars from patt
            }
            i += pattLen - 1;               // increase index...
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
while (i < textLen) {
    printf("%c\n", text[i++]);              // process the end of text
}
```

Above code gives expected output for `"xyz "` and also `"llo"`...

Comment: Thank you, but in some cases, for example, "world", "rld" it doesn't work well with them. Take a look [online compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/BJatRAM4z).

Comment: @LionKing: My bad, I forgot to control what happened what the searched pattern was at the end of the text string => need a `<=` instead of `<`. Previous code was stopping one step too early. Fixed by the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a full substring match *before* you print; mark the applicable characters on a first pass, and then have a second pass to print the results.  In your case, you'd create a second array, with boolean values corresponding to the first, something like

text  = "Hello xyz world";
match    000000111100000

I assume that you can find a basic substring match program online.  Printing on the second pass will be easy: you already have the logic.  Instead of `if (text[i] == patt[j])`, just use `if match[i]`.

Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: An array is not necessary if you keep the index of the first matched charcater after a full match has been found.

Comment: I though of this solution too, i think it is a better answer than me so i upvoted you :)

Comment: @usr2564301 Yeah that is basically like my solution but i prefer this approch

Comment: Thank you. `Is that enough of a hint?` if with a simple example, it will be so good.

Comment: @LionKing: SO is not a coding service.  Where are you stuck in implementing those two steps?

Comment: @Prune: I'm just confused.

Comment: Then you need help beyond the expressed charter of Stack Overflow.  I suggest some on-line tutorials to help you with language and design details, and perhaps a local classmate or tutor.

Answer (score 1):

You should check every letter of your pattern from the beginning (and not check the whole pattern). Try this (not tested):

```
int currIndex = 0;

for (i = 0; i < textLen; i++) {
  printf("%c", text[i]);
  if (text[i] == patt[currIndex]) {
      for (j = 0; j < pattLen; j++) {
          if(text[i+j] != patt[j]){
              continue;
          }
      }
      printf(" <--");
      currIndex++;
      if(currIndex==pattLen)
          currIndex = 0;
  }
  else{
      currIndex = 0;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

**Note:** It is **not** the best way to achieve this but the easiest with your example

**Note 2:** This question should be closed as it is:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Good job, but your code in some cases does not work well. for example, when I changed the target word to "llo" the result was that [The result](http://i.cubeupload.com/L2ITe1.jpg). Concerning your note 2, I think my question is clear, not ambiguous.

Comment: @LionKing Yes you are right i do not reset currIndex when i detect the end of the word. I know your question is clear but it look like you did not search enough for a solution and posted a question too soon :) but maybe i am wrong (i edited my answer but it did not made any error when the index was out of bound?)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Comment: @LionKing People on SO can't solve all your problem... sorry :/